# For frame [laser]: Frame [laser] does not exist

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ubuntu 14.4 indigo. I downloaded this [line extraction packet.](https://github.com/kam3k/laser_line_extraction).
I then `roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch` and  `roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch` to start a husky simulation. Then, I followed the line extraction package instruction and started `roslaunch example.launch`. I checked that both `/line_segments`   and `/line_markers` are giving me outputs by `rostopic echo`. Now, I am trying to make the line marker show up on `rivz`, but I am running into the following error when I added the marker `For frame [laser]: Frame [laser] does not exist` a picture is shown below:
[image: image description]

anyone have suggestions on this? thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299968/for-frame-%5Blaser%5D:-frame-%5Blaser%5D-does-not-exist/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The line extraction node is trying to publish the markers in the `laser` frame, which doesn't exist because you probably haven't provided a transform. You should set the `frame_id` parameter (see package parameter definitions [here](https://github.com/kam3k/laser_line_extraction#parameters)) to a frame which is defined in your [tf_tree](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Debugging%20tools#Viewing_TF_trees).

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-08-07**:
thank you!

**Comment by [mattewthep](https://answers.ros.org/users/52792/mattewthep/) on 2020-05-09**:
Hi, I set the frame_id parameter but as soon as I add the marker display, Rviz crashes, what could it be due to?

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2023-07-28**:
did you solve this, there appear to have no more view_frames command in ros2